# How to generate a table from an entity in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This might be a dumb question but I'm clueless as to how to go about this.

I've got the entity **"MailEntity"**. However, My database does not contain a table that corresponds with this entity yet.

#### Question

I would like to know how to generate the table that corresponds with the Entity I created. I've been looking for this but whatever I search on google, the same results seem to pop up constantly.

#### Update

I've come to know that I can achieve what I want by doing `php app/console doctrine:schema:update`. Adding the `--dump-sql` parameter will dump the sql before the schema is actually updated.

However, I would like to do this for a single Bundle. A single Entity would be even better. I just want to create a table from the `MailEntity` without changing anything else in the database.

Comment: This one: php app/console doctrine:generate:entity ?

Comment: @KA_lin The entity is already generated. I need symfony to do the CREATE TABLE (...) part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the entity classes ready to go, simply run:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

This should list all the queries doctrine needs to run to create the tables. Run the command with the `--force` flag to execute them. It's documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

It might be worth looking at the doctrine migrations bundle, which allows you to *diff* the current DB status with the entities, and generate migration scripts based on that diff [see the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#generating-migrations-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `php app/console doctrine:schema:update`.

This command will tell doctrine to execute the necessary SQL so that your database reflects your doctrine schema. Add `--force` to actually execute the query.

If you want to check the generated SQL command first, you can use `--dump-sql`. It will print what would be executed with `--force`.

[Related documentation you may read for further information](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

**EDIT** : If you want to create the table for a single entity, the easiest way is to dump the generated sql with `--dump-sql` and then extract the line responsible of your MailEntity table creation, then execute it manually.

I would not recommend to do it this way though, you should let Doctrine synchronise your database on its own. This kind of tricks may result in errors in your database.